# Storing Custom Classes in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, data-structures

I need to take existing classes for an iPhone application and store them in a preference/plist/some other data storage format. A good comparison of what I need to store is a gradebook, with the following class structure:

GBGradebook
  + NSArray (GBAssignment)
  + NSArray (GBClasses)
  + NSArray (GBStudent)

GBStudent
  + NSString *studentName
  ...

GBAssignment
  + GBGrade *grade
  ...

GBGrade
  + NSNumber *pointsReceived
  + NSNumber *maxPoints
  ...

That's the basic class structure. What is the best way to store this data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on how to do exactly that using the `NSCoding` protocol and `NSKeyedArchiver` (and its counterpart, `NSKeyedUnarchiver`): http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/nscoding

Basically you implement two methods and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at it, but [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/01_StartingOut.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH105-SW1) may also be an option.  There is also [SQLLitePersistentObjects](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/1198?tstart=0).

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is your best bet. There's a bit of a learning curve, but it is designed to address your storage question as well as provide other benefits, such as SQL-like querying.